# how to end a while loop with a certain variable

Tags: java, if-statement

I am making an odd or even program with a while loop. I am trying to figure out how to end the while loop with a certain number. Right now I have 1 to continue the loop, and trying to make 2 the number that terminates it. Also trying to figure out how to terminate the program if a user types anything but a number like a letter/words.

```
package oddoreven;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class oddoreven {
    public static void main (String[] args){            
        int num;
        int x = 1;
        while(x == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number to check whether or not it is odd or even");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            num = s.nextInt();
            if (num % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println("The number is even");
            else 
                System.out.println("The number is odd");
            //trying to figure out how to get the code to terminate if you put in a value that isn't a number
            System.out.println("Type 1 to continue, 0 to terminate");
            x = s.nextInt();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Having a number to _continue_ and having a number to _terminate_ is the same thing just flipped, why do you need both?  If you type anything _other_ than `1` right now it terminates.

Comment: You can catch an Exception thrown by Scanner if the Input cannot be parsed into number. You can use "break" keyword to exit the loop.

Comment: Yeah do not do what @Mikhail Valiev just suggested, controlling flow of your program with Exceptions is bad practice and a bad habit to get into you.  You don't need to do that.

Comment: @Nexevis TBH neither is exiting a program on an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing you can try is that instead of exiting the program you can just keep asking user to enter correct input and only proceed if they do so. I don't know what is your requirement but if you want to go by good code practice then you shouldn't terminate your program just because user entered wrong input. Imagine if you googled a word with typo and google just shuts off.

Anyways here is how I did it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class oddoreven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        int x = 1;
        while (x == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number to check whether or not it is odd or even");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            boolean isInt = s.hasNextInt(); // Check if input is int
            while (isInt == false) { // If it is not int
                s.nextLine(); // Discarding the line with wrong input
                System.out.print("Please Enter correct input: "); // Asking user again
                isInt = s.hasNextInt(); // If this is true it exits the loop otherwise it loops again
            }
            num = s.nextInt(); // If it is int. It reads the input

            if (num % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println("The number is even");
            else
                System.out.println("The number is odd");
            // trying to figure out how to get the code to terminate if you put in a value
            // that isn't a number
            System.out.println("Type 1 to continue, 0 to terminate");
            x = s.nextInt();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes perfect sense now!

Comment: @TrevorJohnson The goal is to make sure the code keeps looping unless a correct answer is entered. You can make this into a as well function and use it wherever you want. Like when you are asking user to continue or terminate.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use "a real termination condition" in order to terminate a `while` loop (or any loop for that matter); it's cleaner and should be easier to understand by everyone else.

In your case, I think it's better to have a `do`-`while` loop with some condition around this logic: `num % 2 == 0`, and an inner `while` loop for handling user input/validation.

If you still want to break loops abruptly, have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

> If you still need some help with the code, hit me up and I'll sketch up something.

Answer (score 1):

I did not follow the conditions you wanted exactly because it does not make sense to have a *continue* condition AND a *terminate* condition unless there are other options.

What did you want the user to do if he entered `3`, `4` or `5`?  Exit the code or continue the code?  Well if the default is to exit, then you do not need the code to exit on `2` because it already will!  If the default is to continue, then you do not need the continue on `1` and only the exit on `2`.  Thus it is pointless to do both in this case.

Here is the modified code to use a `do while` loop to ensure the loop is entered *at least* 1 time:

```
    int x;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check whether or not it is odd or even");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = s.nextInt();
        if (num % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("The number is even");
        else 
            System.out.println("The number is odd");
        //trying to figure out how to get the code to terminate if you put in a value that isn't a number
        System.out.println("Type 1 to check another number, anything else to terminate.");

        if (!s.hasNextInt()) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            x = s.nextInt();
        }
    } while(x == 1);
   }
```

Note that I added a check to `!s.hasNextInt()` will check if the user enters anything other than an `int`, and will terminate without throwing an `Exception` in those cases by `break`ing from the loop (which is the same as terminating the program in this case).

If the `x` is a valid integer, then `x` is set to the value and then the loop condition checks if `x` is `1`.  If `x` is not `1` the loop terminates, if it is it will continue through the loop another time.

Answer (score 0):

To exit the program when the user enters anything other than a Number, change the variable x type to a String

```
if (!StringUtils.isNumeric(x)) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

To exit the program when user enters 2

```
if (x == 2) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This would not work because he is using `s.nextInt()` to get the value, so you would not be able to set it to a `String`.  Also comparing a `String`  with `==` is also incorrect you would need to use `.equals()` then.  A better way to do this would make a check on the `Scanner` with `hasNextInt()` then terminate if it is not an `int`.